# nloptr::auglag does not take my argument

Tags: r, optimization, parameter-passing, nonlinear-optimization

I am having trouble with the auglag function in the package nloptr. I have a multivariate differentiable nonlinear function to minimise with box constraints and equality constraint. Hence I thought of the function nloptr::auglag. Below you can see what goes wrong (this is not my function, but nicely shows the problem):

```
 x0 <- c(1, 1)
 fn <- function(x, b) return(b * sum(x^2))
 gr <- function(x, b) return(2 * b * x)
 lb <- c(-1, -0.5)
 ub <- c(2, 1.5)

 sol <- nloptr::auglag(x0 = x0, fn = fn, gr = gr, 
            lower = lb, upper = ub, b = 2)
```

I then obtain the following error:

```
 Error in .checkfunargs(eval_grad_f, arglist, "eval_grad_f") :
 eval_grad_f requires argument 'b' but this has not been passed to 
 the 'nloptr' function.
```

This is even without the equality constraint added.

Am I passing the argument in a wrong way?

Comment: `nloptr` has issues. I get the same error as you. So I did the following:
First I removed `gr=gr` and it works. Then I added `b=2` inside the `gr` function and I get this

`Warning message:
In is.nloptr(ret) :
  a gradient was supplied for the objective function, but algorithm NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG does not use gradients.`